# ASP.NET Core Application Insights - Track Authenticated User ID

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I have read everything I could find, and everything suggests using ITelemetryInitializer. However, the best I can figure - that only runs once as its a Singleton. It also runs before the user has authenticated, so I don't have the data I need quite yet.

I have added the logic to my client side tracking as that was pretty straightforward:

```
    @if (_userService != null && _userService.IsAuthenticated())
    {
        <script>
            appInsights.setAuthenticatedUserContext('@_userService.GetCurrentUserId()');
        </script>
    }
```

Note in this case _userService is a DI service I use to access the currently authenticated user (which for now just uses ClaimsPrincipal).

What I need to do now is add the same setting to the server side telemetry, but I can't seem to figure out how to tie-in to it. Anyone out there figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

So I guess this falls into the bucket of "as soon as you as StackOverflow you figure it out yourself".

I don't know what I did wrong, but I do know once I changed my initializer from implementing ITelemetryInitializer to implementing TelemetryInitializerBase, it started working.